# How can I create part of a SOAP message with XSLT and for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have a RaaS which I'm hoping to use to populate a SOAP request.

Below is a sample of the XML output for the RaaS.

```xml
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/User_Based_Security_Groups_Boomerang">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
   <wd:Security_Group wd:Descriptor="Report Writer">
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f73a1d3f08ab01b11964313ad9a0ec59</wd:ID>
    <wd:ID wd:type="Tenant_Security_Group_ID">Report_Writer</wd:ID>
   </wd:Security_Group>
   <wd:workdayID>f73a1d3f08ab01b11964313ad9a0ec59</wd:workdayID>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
   <wd:Security_Group wd:Descriptor="Job and Position Administrator">
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f73a1d3f08ab011edeaa353ad9a0ed59</wd:ID>
    <wd:ID wd:type="Tenant_Security_Group_ID">Job_and_Position_Administrator</wd:ID>
   </wd:Security_Group>
   <wd:workdayID>f73a1d3f08ab011edeaa353ad9a0ed59</wd:workdayID>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
   <wd:Security_Group wd:Descriptor="Organization Administrator">
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f73a1d3f08ab01b9d0e2383ad9a0ee59</wd:ID>
    <wd:ID wd:type="Tenant_Security_Group_ID">Organization_Administrator</wd:ID>
   </wd:Security_Group>
   <wd:workdayID>f73a1d3f08ab01b9d0e2383ad9a0ee59</wd:workdayID>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
```

What I would like to do, is take each "workdayID" element, within each Security Group/Report Entry, and create a SOAP request such as below.  Can I accomplish this with XSLT where I can grab each WID and then repeat my `<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID"></bsvc:ID>` for every WID that is in the RaaS output?

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>true</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Put_Assign_User-Based_Security_Groups_Request bsvc:version="v32.0">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Assign_User-Based_Security_Groups_Data>
            <bsvc:Workday_Account_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="System_User_ID">Someone's ID</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Workday_Account_Reference>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <bsvc:User-Based_Security_Group_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">First workdayID</bsvc:ID>
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">Second workdayID</bsvc:ID>
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">Third workdayID</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:User-Based_Security_Group_Reference>
         </bsvc:Assign_User-Based_Security_Groups_Data>
      </bsvc:Put_Assign_User-Based_Security_Groups_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish. I am quite sure that wrapping an element in `xsl:text` is not the way to accomplish it. Please show a [mcve] including the input and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've made an update to the original post, hopefully, this is clearer for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Couldn't this be handled simply by `<xsl:for each select="wd:Report_Entry"> ...` ?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to figure out, I'm a little new on incorporating XSLT into a SOAP request so would it just look something like ````<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID"><xsl:for each select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:workdayID"></bsvc:ID>````

Comment: @teslawho If you want to output one `bsvc:ID` element for each `wd:workday` element, then you'll need to iterate over those `wd:workday` elements.